# Importing a module does not run the code inside it when running a few unittest files using pytest

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, pytest

I have a few files with tests and an imported file:

```
# test1.py
print("running test1.py")

import unittest
import imported

class MyTest1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method1(self):
        assert "love" == "".join(["lo", "ve"])

    def test_fail1(self):
        assert True, "I failed!"
```

and

```
# test2.py
print("running test2.py")

import unittest
import imported

class MyTest2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ok2(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, 2==2, "I will not appear!")

    def test_fail2(self):
        self.assertFalse(False, "Doh!")
```

and

```
# imported.py
import sys

# Here I am accessing the module that has imported this file
importing = sys.modules[sys._getframe(6).f_globals['__name__']]
print(importing.__name__ + " imported this file")
```

When I run `pytest -s test1.py test2.py`, I get this result:

```
=============================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.7.1, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /Users/ibodi/MyDocs/progs/Python/unittest_test, inifile:
collecting 0 items                                                                 running test1.py
test1 imported this file
collecting 2 items                                                                 running test2.py
collected 4 items                                                                  

test1.py ..                                                                        
test2.py ..

============================= 4 passed in 0.08 seconds =============================
```

`importing` variable in `imported.py` corresponds to the module that has imported the `imported.py` module.

And the problem is that the line `import imported` in `test2.py` doesn't cause `test2 imported this file` to appear in the logs. Why is that?

Comment: Once a module is imported, it is cached in `sys.modules`, so subsequent `import module` calls will not rerun the module code. Add `del sys.modules['imported']` to delete the cached module.

Comment: @hoefling, you are 100% right, it worked.